# How to combine more than one column values into single value as a comma separated string in Oracle SQL (Oracle Forms 12c)

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, concatenation, oracleforms

I have a table named **Data** as below

```
g_name    g_id      v_data    
-----     ----      ------
Test      123        ABC
Test      123        DEG
Test      123        None
Test      123        
Test      123        HIJ
```

I want one select query which returns me values like below(in Oracle Database):

```
Value
------------
Test,123,ABC
Test,123,DEG
...
...
...
```

- `LISTAGG()` function is not working in `Oracle Forms Builder 12c`.
- There may be more than 3 columns. Thus, I need a dynamic way in order
  to combine all columns together.

Can someone help me out here?

Comment: Do you want to keep this logic of concatenating the values in form itself or in database ?

Answer (score 0):

You can concat the values:

```
select g_name || ',' || g_id || ',' || v_data 
from t
```

Comment: Hi Gordon,

That is fine if I have only 3 columns then I can type column names easily in the above query, but suppose if I have more than 50 columns then it will be tedious task. Could you please let me know some dynamic way to concat all columns(I don't want to type all column names)?

LISTAGG and some other functions are not working in Oracle Forms builder 12c.

Comment: **LISTAGG** and some other functions(like **within group** are not working in Oracle Forms builder 12c.

Comment: @AnujSingh . . . `LISTAGG()` is not appropriate for this problem, because all the values you want to aggregate are in the same row.

Answer (score 0):

Please perform concatenation

```
select g_name||','||g_id||','||v_data from data;
```

You can write a dynamic query in plsql and achieve this.

```
select LISTAGG(column_name, ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY column_name) as colum_name from cols where table_name = 'DATA';
```

Pass this result to a column using `into` clause.

Comment: That is fine if I have only 3 columns then I can type column names easily in the above query, but suppose if I have more than 50 columns then it will be tedious task. Could you please let me know some dynamic way to concat all columns(I don't want to type all column names)?

Comment: to dynamically do that you need a piece of PL/SQL code with table name as parameter to get you the dynamic query as output. You can't do that in SQL. Do you want this in the answer ??

Comment: Hi Jim,

**LISTAGG** and some other functions(like **within group** are not working in Oracle Forms builder 12c.

Comment: Yes @Roberto that answer will be fine.

Comment: Yes LISTAGG will help you. `select LISTAGG(column_name, ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY column_name) from cols where table_name = 'required_table';` But it has to be done in plsql. Are you fine with that?

Comment: @JimMacaulay I have to use my plsql code within Oracle Forms 12c builder, there LISTAGG is not working.

Comment: That's not working @JimMacaulay, LISTAGG doesn't work in Oracle Forms.

Comment: @JimMacaulay You should add context that LISTAGG  should be use with 'GROUP BY'

Answer (score 0):

If you have an option to create a function in your database, perhaps you can retrieve the result of the function as the query you want to execute

Let me show you an example:

1.I create a table with 6 columns.

```
 create table test.mytest ( c1 number, c2 number , c3 number, c4 varchar2(10) , c5 number, c6 number );
```

2.I create a function to retrieve the query ( or you can invoke as an anonymus plsql block )

```
create or replace function test.p_gen_query ( powner in varchar2 , ptable in varchar2, p_pretty in varchar2 default 'N' )
 return clob
 as
 vowner     varchar2(40)  := upper(powner);
 vtable     varchar2(128) := upper(ptable);
 vconta     pls_integer;
 vsql       clob;
 out_string varchar2(128);
 cursor c_tab_columns
 is
 select column_name, count(*) over () tot_rows
 from all_tab_columns where table_name = vtable and owner = vowner
 order by column_id;
 begin
 vsql := ' select ' ;
 for item in c_tab_columns
 loop
 out_string := item.COLUMN_NAME;
 if c_tab_columns%rowcount = 1 then
 dbms_lob.append(vsql,out_string||' || '','' || ');
 elsif c_tab_columns%rowcount < item.tot_rows then
 dbms_lob.append(vsql,out_string||' || '','' || ');
 else
 dbms_lob.append(vsql,out_string||' from '||vowner||'.'||vtable||' ');
 end if;
 end loop;
 if p_pretty = 'Y'
 then
   dbms_lob.append(vsql,''||chr(10)||'');
   dbms_lob.append(vsql,' ; ');
 end if;
 return vsql;
 end;
 /
```

3.Call the function with p_pretty as 'N' ( retrieves the query without sql terminator )

```
SQL> set long 99999999 longchunksize 9999 lines 9999 pages 0
SQL> select test.p_gen_query ( 'TEST' , 'MYTEST' ) from dual ;

 select C1 || ',' || C2 || ',' || C3 || ',' || C4 || ',' || C5 || ',' || C6 from TEST.MYTEST
```

4.Call the function with p_pretty as 'Y' to get it with sql terminator

```
 SQL> select test.p_gen_query ( 'TEST' , 'MYTEST' , 'Y' ) from dual ;
 select C1 || ',' || C2 || ',' || C3 || ',' || C4 || ',' || C5 || ',' || C6 from TEST.MYTEST
 ;
```

This way you can use it for any query you want to build in that way. I guess you can retrieve the result from Oracle Forms.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you need a primary key column ( call `id` *which I asssume as the first column within the columns list* ) for the table.

Then you need to create a stored function which contains both `LISTAGG()` function, which will be used to combine column names derived from one of the dictionary views giving column names such as `user_tab_columns`,`user_tab_cols` or just `col` through concatenetion , and Dynamic Query returning the concatenated columns for each `id` value.

So, create the function within the database by ;

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_value( i_id Data.id%type ) RETURN VARCHAR2 IS 
  v_out   VARCHAR2(32767); 
BEGIN
  SELECT LISTAGG(column_name, '|| '','' ||') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY column_id)
    INTO v_out
    FROM cols 
   WHERE table_name = 'DATA'
     AND column_id > 1; 
 
  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'SELECT '||v_out||' FROM Data WHERE id = :v_id' INTO v_out USING i_id; 
  RETURN v_out;

END;
/
```

And call from Forms as a regular query statement :

```
SELECT id, get_value( id ) AS value
  FROM Data
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=f02896b7c9d99e682959ac1dcd0490a1)</kbd>